# Images stopped showing using Smart Lencioni Image Resizer

Tags: image-resizing

I don't know what I did, but for some reason images stopped working. Some browsers show the image, but the majority don't. I'm using v1.4.1 of [Lencioni Image Resizer](http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/)

This image will not show:
http://www.norwegianfashion.no/wp-content/themes/norwegianfashion/image.php?width=280&height=&cropratio=2:1&image=http://www.norwegianfashion.no/wp-content/uploads/magazine/issue5/siri1_72dpi.jpg

But you can access the image here:
http://www.norwegianfashion.no/wp-content/uploads/magazine/issue5/siri1_72dpi.jpg

If I change `&` with `&amp;`, I get the message `Error: no image was specified`.
http://www.norwegianfashion.no/wp-content/themes/norwegianfashion/image.php?width=280&height=&cropratio=2:1&image=http://www.norwegianfashion.no/wp-content/uploads/magazine/issue5/siri1_72dpi.jpg

Another place I'm using it, is here, and that works fine:
http://www.advicis.no/wp-content/themes/business1/image.php?width=150&height=&cropratio=1:1&image=http://www.advicis.no/wp-content/uploads/OD-puzzle-large.jpg

What could cause this?

Comment: Since these links are all broken, this close reason now applies: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm updating my site and the new version will not be using LIR. So this can be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the images are no longer available and will not be available in the new version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your PHP script cannot access the url http://www.norwegianfashion.no/wp-content/uploads/magazine/issue5/siri1_72dpi.jpg.

I can, and you can, but the server on which the PHP script is running can't.

Perhaps the PHP server doesn't have the right pluging installed to do HTTP requests, or the HTTP server blocks requests coming from within.

Can you insert some debugging into image.php showing the results of each step? Or post the part of the image.php code where it retrieves the image?

Can you login to the PHP server with SSH and see if you can execute:

```
wget http://www.norwegianfashion.no/wp-content/uploads/magazine/issue5/siri1_72dpi.jpg
```

Another solution is to let image.php grab the file from the local disk instead of through a HTTP request, but that requires some redesign of that script.

Comment: @littlegreen: Actually, looking in Firebug under Net->Images, I get a 404 Not Found (on the complete URL) - but we both see that the iamge is tehre. image.php is also there. There is no debug option here :(

Comment: Yes. The image is there. It can be accessed from outside using direct URL. image.php is also there. It can be accessed from outside. But the script image.php cannot access the URL. You should edit the image.php script, adding lines like 'echo $filename', 'echo $errormessage' in order to debug the problem.

Comment: @ littlegreen: I did and I found where in the code it "crashed" - but it didn't make sense. So I contacted the developer of the plugin and he scratched his jead too. What we ended up doing, was using the latest version of SLIR 2.x. Now It's up working again. I'll give you cred for helping me :)

Comment: OK, so then the image.php could **access** the url, but couldn't parse the image... but what does image.php do with the image besides tranferring it to the browser? Is there some kind of recoding or detection? Anyway, I'm happy that you could debug the problem and solve it, even though my hunch was incorrect. Thanks for the (half-deserved ;) credit.

Comment: image.php takes the image, resizes it and saves a copy in a cash directory, using a hash name created from image info. Then it checks the cash if the image exist new. If not, it uses the cashed image.  It resizes on the fly, therefore I only need to upload one image and use image.php to output image size.